# Why is python automatically putting a \ infront of '?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, findall

Pretty much as question states- I have a code that finds sentences in a big string using regex- `findall()`. It then uses this sentence later, however when it uses it it  puts a backslash infront of any apostrophe, for example `Today's` becomes `Today\'s`. Why is this happening, and how can I stop this happening?

Comment: Include relevant demonstration / sscce code and output.

Answer (score 1):

It's called escaping a string. When you use `"` or `'` inside of a string use `\` to avoid lexical syntax errors. I believe there is a method that removes the escape character from a string if that's what you'd like to do.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash denotes a so called escape sequence, which basically tells python that this character has to be interpreted differently from a "normal" ' character (which would signal the beginning or end of a string for the interpreter).